# How should I make a text widget supporting a simple markup language?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

The Torque engine has a nice markup language TorqueML (see below, copied from [a post in the garagegames forum](http://www.garagegames.com/community/forums/viewthread/50165)). It makes it possible to incorporate some simple layout and format information in pure text, which can be used to build a text widget for help, or dialogs, in a game.

I would like to know if one can suggest a most efficient way to build/get the same feature in Haxe (especially within the HaxeFlixel framework).

Here is the markup language info available in Torque, for reference:

```
<font:fontName:fontSize> - sets the font and fontsize as indicated. Example: <font:Arial Bold:20>  
<tag:???> - not sure what this does  
<color:rrggbb> - sets text color in hex format. Example: <color:ff0000> will display red text  
<bitmap:filePath> - displays a bitmap image indicated by the file path. Example: <bitmap:demo/client/ui/seperator>  
<spush> - saves the current text formatting so that temporary changes to formatting can be made. Used with spop.  
<spop> - restores the previously saved text formatting. Used with spush. See the file "3. Gui Editor.hlf" included with the TGE demo for an example of usage.  
<sbreak> - not sure what this does  
<just:left> - left justify  
<just:right> - right justify  
<just:center> - center justify  
<a:ExternalURL>LinkTitle</a> - inserts a hyperlink into the text which will open the user's browser.  
The external URL does not need the "http://" format. Example: <a:www.garagegames.com>Garage Games Website</a>  
<lmargin: ##> - sets the left margin  
<lmargin%: ##> - sets the left margin (not sure what the % does)  
<rmargin: ##> - sets the right margin  
<rmargin%: ##> - sets the right margin (not sure what the % does)  
<clip:> - not sure what this does  
<div:> - not sure what this does  
<tab:##(,##,etc)> - sets the tab stops (multiple tabs are separated by commas)  
 - Breaks the current line and begins a new one.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, there is a rudimentary function already available in HaxeFlixel's FlxText.hx that lets you apply simple markup:

https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel/blob/dev/flixel/text/FlxText.hx#L274

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting. It's really good already. The main remaining features seem to be including images and hyperlink. I guess in general images can be handled separately from the text (for example: help topics can have one image + text, that's it). For hyperlinks I still don't know how to do this.

Comment: For hyperlinks what you would probably need to do is use getCharBoundaries() on the underlying text field to identify the visual location of the characters that make up the hyperlink. Then, you would need to create a transparent or invisible FlxButton (or FlxUIButton or some other such widget) that sits at that location. Then you could use that to drive a link.


For full html markup, keep in mind there is an API in the regular textField for htmlText, but not sure how well filled in it is. FlxTexts just fall through to rendering the underlying text, so it might make sense to work on that level

Comment: Thanks Larsiusprime this answers the question really well.